# Not getting any clue to integrate Gmail API using .NET framework in vs2017. I wanted to send the input data of the Web form to a user's email .

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

The official Gmail API  documentation is horrendous.  Not getting any clue to integrate Gmail API using .NET framework in vs2017.  I wanted to send the input data of the Web form to a user's email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: I already sent using smtp but now i want to integrate with Gmail api and send it . I couldn't understand the .net documentation of the Gmail api.

Comment: this link will be helpful, it really easy to implement 
 https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: already tired but it's not working idk why

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where did you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a three step process -

1. Define an HTML template which which describes how your mail should be presented.
2. Write a small c# code to replace all place holders like your form fields , user name, etc.

   ```
    private string createEmailBody(string userName, string title, string message)  

   {  

   string body = string.Empty;  
   //using streamreader for reading my htmltemplate   

   using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/HtmlTemplate.html")))  

   {  

       body = reader.ReadToEnd();  

   }  

   body = body.Replace("{UserName}", userName); //replacing the required things  

   body = body.Replace("{Title}", title);  

   body = body.Replace("{message}", message);  
   //// Instead of message add you own parameters.

   return body;
   ```

   }
3. When form is submitted, call step 2 code first.  Then use it's output to set mail body.

Code would be something like -

```
string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
int portNumber = 587;
bool enableSSL = true;

/// This mail from can just be a display only mail I'd 
string emailFrom = "no-reply@gmail.com";

string subject = "your subject";
string body = createEmailBody();

using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
{
mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
mail.To.Add(emailTo);
/// Add more to IDs if you want to send it to multiple people.

mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
// This is required to keep formatting of your html contemts

/// Add attachments if you want, this is optional
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(yourfilepath));


   using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
    {
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(your-smtp-account-email, your-smtp-account-password);
    smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
    smtp.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

Refer this link for working example

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/33b051/sending-mail-with-html-template/

**EDIT: For using GMail API**
Using GMAIL APIs you will need two nuget packages:
 1. Install-Package Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 
 2. Install-Package AE.Net.Mail

Code is very similar to what we have for normal SMTP mail send.  It is explained at: http://jason.pettys.name/2014/10/27/sending-email-with-the-gmail-api-in-net-c/

Comment: thankx. i used this already when sending by SMTP
but now i need to integrate with Gmail API.
any code for that?

Comment: check if [this link](http://jason.pettys.name/2014/10/27/sending-email-with-the-gmail-api-in-net-c/) helps.